# Use iOS GKMinmaxStrategist with 3+ Players

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

When using GKMinmaxStrategist with 2 Players (Human vs AI) the Strategist calls `score(for player: GKGameModelPlayer) -> Int` 
one time per each of the possible moves. (Which is the correct behavior).

However if I bump up the players to 3 (e.g. Human vs AI vs AI) the Strategist calls the same score function 3 consecutive times per possible move rather than 1 time per move. (This is a hugely unnecessary waste of compute cycles).

Any ideas how to prevent the strategist from wasting time on the same function?

The 3 players are defined under: class Player: NSObject, GKGameModelPlayer

```
static var allPlayers = [
        Player(.player1),
        Player(.player2),
        Player(.player3)
    ]
```

Commenting out the 3rd player results in the current number of `score()` calls

The players are pass to the game model under: class Board: NSObject, GKGameModel

```
public var players: [GKGameModelPlayer]? {
        return Player.allPlayers
    }
```

Expected:

```
apply selected move.option (8, 5)
score(for player: "Test1")
score 0
apply selected move.option (5, 4)
score(for player: "Test1")
score 10
```

Problem:

```
apply selected move.option (8, 5)
score(for player: "Test1")
score 0
score(for player: "Test1")
score 0                              <- unnecessary  re-call of score()
score(for player: "Test1")
score 0                              <- unnecessary  re-call of score()
apply selected move.option (5, 4)
score(for player: "Test1")
score 10
score(for player: "Test1")
score 10                              <- unnecessary  re-call of score()  
score(for player: "Test1")
score 10                              <- unnecessary  re-call of score()
```

I can't post my entire code but you can easily replicate this problem by downloading this fully functional [tutorial](http://@nathan%20%20%20%20You%20can%20replicate%20the%20problem%20%20by%20downloading%20this%20completed%20tutorial%20[https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/10/TicTacToe-Final-2.zip]) from Razeware .

On Board.swift add these directly inside their respective functions:

```
print("apply(_ gameModelUpdate:")
print("score(for: player) -> Int ")
```

Run and you'll see just two lines per possible move:

```
apply(_ gameModelUpdate:
score(for: player)
```

Then, on Player.swift add a 3rd player using these lines in their respective spots:

```
case test

case .test:
        return "test"

Player(. test)
```

You will now see the following per possible move:

```
apply(_ gameModelUpdate:
score(for: player)
score(for: player)
score(for: player)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using? Also, in general, I would avoid premature-optimization. Don't worry about an "unnecessary waste of compute cycles" until you've ran a performance analysis and identify this as a bottleneck.

Comment: @nathan    I cannot post the code in its entirety (NDA). I have added how the players are defined and passed to the Strategist.  In short if the Strategist receives a list of 2 Player objects, there is no issue. If the strategist receives more Players it begins unnecessarily calling the score function.  In this case I don't need a performance analysis to know this is an issue. The time to process score() is averaging 0.475 seconds per pass so two extra calls is an 0.95 wasted seconds per turn for a 3 player game. This results in the time per turn too so slow to maintain user engagement.

Comment: @nathan added a way for you to replicate the problem with far simpler example.

Comment: @MichaelGarito as a possible solution, you can create array / dictionary with scores, calculate them on apply func and just return value from it on score call.